# Rails: Is there a built translation for "ago"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, internationalization, rails-i18n

Rails translate time ago with `time_ago_in_words` and documentation is [this](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper/time_ago_in_words).

```
time_ago_in_words(3.minutes.from_now)                 # => 3 minutes
```

However, in our app, we use `"ago": 3 minutes ago`

So, what is the best way to translate when "ago" appears before the `time_ago`, such as in ***French***:

Il y a 3 minutes

Is this built into Rails?

Using *Rails 4.2.10* and *rails-i18n gem* which provides the distance in time, but not the "ago".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you just need to pass the time as a variable to the translation.
Then in the language `yml`s, you can have the rest of the string where it needs to be.

Suppose that `@product.purchased_time_ago` returns the `time_ago_in_words()`.

```
# app/views/products/show.html.erb
<%= t('time_ago', time: @product.purchased_time_ago) %>

# config/locales/en.yml
en:
  time_ago: "%{time} ago"

# config/locales/fr.yml
fr:
  time_ago: "Il y a %{time}"
```

This is direct taken from the [docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#passing-variables-to-translations).

Answer (score 4):

You could use custom scopes:

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/fc5dd0b85189811062c85520fd70de8389b55aeb/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/date_helper.rb#L75

```
time_ago_in_words(3.minutes.ago, scope: 'datetime.distance_in_words_ago') # => 3 minutes ago
```

and you need to add this to your locale (en.yml)

```
en:
  datetime:
    distance_in_words_ago:
      x_days:
        one: 1 day ago
        other: "%{count} days ago"
      x_minutes:
        one: 1 minute ago
        other: "%{count} minutes ago"
      x_months:
        one: 1 month ago
        other: "%{count} months ago"
      x_years:
        one: 1 year ago
        other: "%{count} years ago"
      x_seconds:
        one: 1 second ago
        other: "%{count} seconds ago"
```

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/fc5dd0b85189811062c85520fd70de8389b55aeb/actionview/lib/action_view/helpers/date_helper.rb#L78

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It's a pity that it's not included the de facto standard `rails-i18n` gem. The same case pops up when doing German translation, namely:
`about one hour` is `etwa eine Stunde` 
but! `about one hour ago` is `vor etwa einer Stunde`.
Note that not only `vor` was added, but also an extra `r` in `einer` was necessary.